# How to evaluate Learning To Rank XGBoost

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost, ranking

I am new to using the Learning to Rank method with XGBRanker. My data contains every possible combination of qid | customer data | product data | was_buy (0,1). I have prepared a model using XGBRanker with the goal of recommending the top K products for each customer (I'm not sure if it's correct, but I believe so). However, my question is, how can I validate the results?

1. I prepared the data, defined qid, split the data into training and
   testing. I saved important information (product ID and user email)
   for backup to interpret the results and deleted them from the data
   that will enter the models.

```
# Rozdelenie dát na vstupné premenné a label
X = df.drop('was_buy', axis=1)
y = df['was_buy']

# Add qid (email)
qid = X['email'].factorize()[0]  # Konverzia emailu na číselné hodnoty pre qid

# Split data into train and test 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, qid_train, qid_test = train_test_split(X, y, qid, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=y)

# Save and delete identifiers
train_email_ids = X_train['email'].copy()
train_entity_ids = X_train['entity_id'].copy()
test_email_ids = X_test['email'].copy()
test_entity_ids = X_test['entity_id'].copy()
X_train = X_train.drop(['email', 'entity_id'], axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop(['email', 'entity_id'], axis=1)

# Sor data by qid
sort_idx_train = qid_train.argsort()
X_train = X_train.iloc[sort_idx_train]
y_train = y_train.iloc[sort_idx_train]
qid_train = qid_train[sort_idx_train]
train_entity_ids = train_entity_ids.iloc[sort_idx_train]

sort_idx_test = qid_test.argsort()
X_test = X_test.iloc[sort_idx_test]
y_test = y_test.iloc[sort_idx_test]
qid_test = qid_test[sort_idx_test]
test_entity_ids = test_entity_ids.iloc[sort_idx_test]
```

2. I defined an "ndcg_scorer" because I needed to use it for
   optimization, since it does not exist directly in the library, I had
   to define it this way.

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, ndcg_score

# Define scoring function
def ndcg_scorer(y_true, y_pred):
    return ndcg_score([y_true], [y_pred])

# Prepare scorer object
ndcg_scorer = make_scorer(ndcg_scorer, needs_proba=False, greater_is_better=True)

#I define params here and optimize model vy Random Search
```

3. I reran the model with top parameters and got the results.

```
best_parameters = random_search.best_params_

ranker_optimized = xgb.XGBRanker(
    tree_method="hist",
    objective="rank:ndcg",
    n_estimators=100,
    **best_parameters  # Unpacking the best parameters
)

ranker_optimized.fit(X_train, y_train, qid=qid_train)
preds_optimized = ranker_optimized.predict(X_test)

# Final dataframe, where i add identifiers of customer and product
result_df_optimized = pd.DataFrame({
    'email': test_email_ids.values[sort_idx_test],
    'entity_id': test_entity_ids.values[sort_idx_test],
    'pred_value': preds_optimized
})
```

4. How can I now define metrics to evaluate the model, please?